# Issue with converting String to Date

Tags: java, datetime

I tried to convert a String to Date by the following way in Java:

```
public static Date dateConv1(String s){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss");
        String dateInString = s;
        Date date = new Date();
```

It converts the noon 12:00-12:59 as midnight i.e 00:00-00:59. Could soeone let me know how I should solve this issue?

Comment: @YCF_L hmmm sounds like an answer *to me*, with proper explanations

Comment: @Eugene I think I makes a mistake with that comment, my bad I read the question in a mirror :(!! The question still not clear enough, the OP should explain more

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is long outdated along with `Date` and notoriously troublesome too. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

HH - means hours

Reach to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and see all the examples you need.

Answer (score 0):

The String is not correctly formated. hh means 1-12 hours. There are 4 way to format hours (hh, HH, kk, KK).
Here you can read about the formatting:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss");
```

" hh " is for 12 hours format change it to

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```